# Status change message in chat window in Miranda

Tags: settings, chat, status, xmpp, icq

Can somebody help me, how to disable bothering status messages in Miranda window chat? I mean messages like:

- ...signed on and is now Online.
- ...signed on and is now Away.
- ...changed status from Away to DND.
- ...changed status from DND to Away.
- ...changed status from Away to Online.
- ...signed off.
- etc.

I use Cult pack with IEView plugin. I tried many settings, but status messages are still shown. I am puzzled. Thanks for help.

[image: Chat window]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem using default message log module. So I disabled IEView plugin (in settings -> message sessions -> message log -> global message log display), which Miranda Cult Pack used for display message chat. After that, I configured some options, colors and it looks great!

Answer (score 1):

Try to uncheck "Show status changes" in Options - Message Sessions - Messaging Log:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/JwLhO.jpg

Answer (score 0):

If you are using newest Miranda NG - show/hide status changes in message windows is in
Options > Message Sessions > General > Other options > Log status changes

[image: Miranda NG window]